# Получение данных с Telegram getUpdates на javascript с помощью XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, telegram, xmlhttprequest

На странице сайта есть чат, который отправляет сообщения в заранее указанный chat_id от имени бота.
С отправкой сообщений никаких проблем нет, а вот как получить данные о новых входящих я никак не могу понять.

На данный момент у меня есть код, который получает последнее сообщение в общем массиве данных, хранящихся в [https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/getUpdates?offset=-1](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7BTOKEN%7D/getUpdates?offset=-1), но проблема в том, что мне нужно получать данные только при появлении нового сообщения. Как я могу периодически "ловить", то есть отслеживать новые данные при их появлении? И как распарсить ответ сервера, чтобы получить только содержимое сообщения?

```
var HttpClient = function() {
              this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
                  var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                  anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
                      if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                          aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
                  }
          
                  anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );            
                  anHttpRequest.send( null );
                }
            }
            
            function GetAsync() {
              var client = new HttpClient();
              client.get('https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/getUpdates?offset=-1', function(response) {
                  alert(response)
              });
            }
```

При вызове функции я получаю alert с таким содержанием:

{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":69sdf38324,
"message":{"message_id":36,"from":{"id":34sfa5747,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"ghj","last_name":"ghj","username":"ghjghj","language_code":"ru"},"chat":{"id":341735747,"first_name":"ghjjs","last_name":"ghjghj","username":"ghjghj","type":"private"},"date":1648326116,"text":"asdasdas"}}]}

Comment: Использовать цикл желательно задержкой по времени. Можно через вебхук телеграмма ну тут нужен сервер

Comment: Получается, что нет какого то автоматического способа отслеживания изменения данных? только посылать периодические запросы и вручную отслеживать изменения?

Comment: Да. может вам будет  интересно https://habr.com/ru/post/447006/